# OPTION_HEATMAP not defined using GR for Julia plotting

Tags: plot, runtime-error, julia, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap in julia using gr() and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: OPTION_HEATMAP not defined
 in gr_display at /home/cameron/.julia/v0.4/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:768
 in gr_display at /home/cameron/.julia/v0.4/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:455
 in _display at /home/cameron/.julia/v0.4/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:990
```

I tried plotting just a heatmap using rand using this example from the plots documentation:

```
 xs = [string("x",i) for i = 1:10] 
 ys = [string("y",i) for i = 1:4]
 z = float((1:4) * (1:10)')
 heatmap(xs,ys,z,aspect_ratio=1)
```

It still gives me the same error. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on Gitter this problem is due to using an outdated version of Julia and Plots.